# How to configure Bean for rssView with annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to add rss source for my site in spring and the final step is configure the Bean of CustomRssView.

but tutorial used xml to configure it. I hope to use @Bean annotation. However, It's failed to resolve the view name.

xml in tutorial

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

<!-- Map returned view name "rssViewer" to bean id "rssViewer" -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />

<bean id="rssViewer" class="com.mkyong.common.rss.CustomRssViewer" />
```

my bean configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public RssView rssView() {
        return new RssView();
    }
}
```

It is successful to register, but the view name is not resolved by BeanNameViewResolver.

some debug info

```
2015-09-08 16:02:13.103 TRACE 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod : Method [getRssFeed] returned [ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'rssView'; model is {rss=[Post(id=0, menuId=0, submenuId=0, date=null, author=admin, title=Spring MVC Tutorial 1, content=Tutorial 1 Content ...), Post(id=0, menuId=0, submenuId=0, date=null, author=system, title=Spring MVC Tutorial 2, content=Tutorial 2 Content ...)]}]
2015-09-08 16:02:13.103 TRACE 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite : Testing if return value handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler@46a550ec] supports [class org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView]
2015-09-08 16:02:13.111 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2015-09-08 16:02:13.111 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'rssView'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.113 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'rssView'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.113 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.
2015-09-08 16:02:13.113 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'rssView'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.113 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.113 TRACE 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceViewResolver   : Cached view [rssView]
2015-09-08 16:02:13.114 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'rssView'; URL [rssView]] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.114 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'rssView'; URL [rssView]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.114 TRACE 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Rendering view with name 'rssView' with model {rss=[Post(id=0, menuId=0, submenuId=0, date=null, author=admin, title=Spring MVC Tutorial 1, content=Tutorial 1 Content ...), Post(id=0, menuId=0, submenuId=0, date=null, author=system, title=Spring MVC Tutorial 2, content=Tutorial 2 Content ...)]} and static attributes {}
2015-09-08 16:02:13.114 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Added model object 'rss' of type [java.util.ArrayList] to request in view with name 'rssView'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.116 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to resource [rssView] in InternalResourceView 'rssView'
2015-09-08 16:02:13.125 TRACE 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@41e5804f
2015-09-08 16:02:13.125 DEBUG 21367 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

how to change my code.

Comment: tutorial link http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-rss-feed-example/

Comment: Because there is no `BeanNameViewResolver` only an `InternalResourceViewResolver`. Register a `BeanNameViewResolver` (Just as in your xml sample) and make sure it executes before the `InternalResourceViewResolver`.

Comment: But spring-boot has auto registered a `BeanNameViewResolver`. The problem is that the bean never be resolved by `BeanNameViewResolver`. I have tried to change the order, but it didn't work.@M.Deinum

Comment: The issue is that there is also a `ContentNegotiationViewResolver` and because the content type is `text/html` it resolves it with the `InternalResourceViewResolver`. When requesting rss make sure the incoming request is requesting for `application/rss+xml`. Or add the `BeanNameViewResolver` and name it `viewResolver` to override the content negotiation one.

Comment: Thanks!! I have solved it.